# Regex catching function parameters in php

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

Currently I am trying to get all function parameters with regex for templating. The function parameters will be much like PHP compitable.

So here is the sample text needed to be parsed:

```
"test", 'test2', $test3, ?"%A %d %B %Y", "foo,bar,foobar"
```

This needed to be parsed to:

```
[
    '"test"',
    '\'test2\'',
    '$test3',
    '?"%A %d %B %Y"',
    '"foo,bar,foobar"'
]
```

I found this pattern but. When it has commas (,) in between double quotes it splits them too.

```
'~([^,]+\(.+?\))|([^,]+)~x'
```

The result of this pattern is:

```
[
    '"test"',
    ' \'test2\'',
    ' $test3',
    ' ?"%A %d %B %Y"',
    ' "foo,',
    'bar,',
    'foobar"'
]
```

I am not very good with regex patterns. I can achieve basic things with it but I couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Can there be escaped quotes?

Comment: In the source string? Yes there could be. It can be something like: `'test', $test2, "foo,bar\"test", 'bar\'s foo test,'`

Comment: Why in the world not use `$result = explode(', ', $string);`???

Comment: Because it will catch the commas in the double/single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not handle many things, and one of them is the double quoted value after a space. As the beginning has no optional whitespace pattern, the last alternative triggers, and stops at a comma.

You can use the following regex:

```
\s*("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|[^,]+),?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM3vD1/1), and grab Capture Group 1 values.

Here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/FclxEf):

```
$re = '~\s*("[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\"]*)*"|\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\\']*)*\'|[^,]+),?~'; 
$str = "\"test\", 'test2', \$test3, ?\"%A %d %B %Y\", \"foo,bar,foobar\""; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $tokens);
print_r($tokens[1]);
```

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|[^,]+)` - either of the 3 alternatives:

  - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"` - double quoted strings (supporting escaped sequences)
  - `|` - or
  - `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'` - single quoted strings (supporting escaped sequences)
  - `|` - or
  - `[^,]+` - 1+ characters other than a comma
- `,?` - an optional comma (`?` - one or zero occurrences)